# How to make js alerts pop only on php echo messages and not on everything else?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a problem after pressing the like button with javascript. It pops the empty alert window.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function like(btn) {
        var username = '<?php echo $username ?>';
        var dataString = 'username=' + username;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'ajaxjs.php',
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                alert(html);
                }
            });
    }
```

ajaxjs.php file:

```
include ('./include/connect.php');
$username = $_POST['username'];
if ($username == "") {
echo "You are not logged in";   
} else {
mysql_query("INSERT INTO likes VALUES('','$username')");
}
```

I want it to pop the window only when `if ($username == "") { echo "You are not logged in";`

But not if the ajaxjs.php ends up running the query. How do I keep it for echo, but prevent it for `mysql_query("INSERT INTO likes VALUES('','$username')");`?

Comment: Use an `if` statement in your success function!?

Answer (score 2):

You need to check `html` result in your javascript-code using [if](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp) statement.

```
function like(btn) {
    var username = '<?php echo $username ?>';
    var dataString = 'username=' + username;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajaxjs.php',
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
               if(html.length > 0) {
                 alert(html);
               }

            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
alert(html);
```

Use

```
html.length && alert(html);
```

Comment: Wow that was simple. Thanks! I'm just wondering what does it do? I mean, how is it preventing the alert?

Comment: It checks the length of the outputted text.  If it's 0 then it's interpreted as false and doesn't execute the next statement, the alert.  So if you don't output anything, then it won't alert anything.